# Matlab Bulk Update MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, matlab

I want to update a MySQL table from matlab in bulk. The current logic that I use iterates over the array and inserts it one-by-one which takes way too long.

Here is my current implementation-

```
function update_table(customer_id_list, cluster_id_list, write_conn)
    num_customers = size(customer_id_list, 1);
    for idx=1:num_customers+1
        customer_id = customer_id_list(idx);
        cluster_id = cluster_id_list(idx);
        sql = strcat(sql, 'UPDATE table SET cluster_id = ', num2str(cluster_id), ' WHERE customer_id = ', num2str(customer_id));
        exec(write_conn, sql);
    end
end
```

Tried to look for documentation to do bulk update/insert, but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Use SQL transactions. See docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Do an "upjoin" using a temporary table.

- Build your update specification as a Matlab `table` array with all the `cluster_id` and `customer_id` pairs that specify the new values.
- Create a SQL temporary table that contains columns for the key columns you'll be matching on and the columns to update.

  - `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table SELECT customer_id, cluster_id FROM table WHERE 1 = 0`
- Batch-insert your update specification data from Matlab into the temporary table using Matlab Database Toolbox's `datainsert` or `sqlwrite`.
- Update the target table en masse by joining it to the temp table: `UPDATE table SET targ.cluster_id = upd.cluster_id FROM table targ INNER JOIN my_temp_table upd ON targ.customer_id = upd.customer_id`.
- Drop the temp table.

Boom. If you're going to do this a lot, wrap it up in a generic `upjoin()` function.

See the Matlab documentation for `datainsert` and `sqlwrite`. Do not use `fastinsert`; despite its name, it is much slower than `datainsert` and `sqlwrite`.